# What are contents in a TTF file and how is it placed?

Tags: fonts, truetype

I am trying to create an app that takes all english characters in users own handwriting via a physical scanner and converts it into a `.ttf` file. I want to do this programmatically without using any font editor like FontForge.

So can anyone tell me what are the contents in a `.ttf` file? I opened up a `.ttf` file on my MacBook Pro `FontBook.app` and saw only characters written in that particular style. But how were they written in that `.ttf` file? Any idea? please help.

Answer (score 2):

The TTF specification has all of the details regarding how TTF files can be laid out. It is 90 pages long https://www.microsoft.com/typography/tt/ttf_spec/ttch02.doc.

To answer your question: The first three pages of that document give you the basic file structure.

As you work through the specification it may be helpful to open an existing TTF file in a hex editor so you can walk through and see the actual bytes that make up a TTF.

A much more practical approach would be to use an existing library. A quick Google search led me to Fontastic http://code.andreaskoller.com/libraries/fontastic/ which looks (in my opinion) hundreds of times easier than manually creating your own TTF file.

Comment: i have read about fontastic. but its documentation is not good. can you write an example code for me?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't actually used the library. But that's probably a good thing to post as a new question.

Comment: but can you please please please help me out using that library and create a ttf just for character 'a' and post the code?